# Distinct records on Select statement ORACLE-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table with possible duplicate records except one field i.e Field2 in below table. Field1 is Key to join Table.

```
Field1  Field2  Field3
  aa      T       qqq
  aa      F       qqq
  bb      F       eee
  cc      T       rrr
```

Now in Field2, if T and F both are there for same Field1, I want to select row with T as Field 2 values. 
In case only T or F is available I want that record.
So output of the Select statement should be be

```
Field1  Field2  Field3
  aa      T      qqq
  bb      F      eee
  cc      T      rrr
```

Help me if there is efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement I would use:

```
select 
   Field1,  
   max(Field2) as Field2,
   max(Field3) keep(dense_rank first order by Field2 desc) as Field3
from 
   table
group by 
   Field1;
```

The third column function gets the corresponding row to Field2.

Comment: I dont know what keep (dense_rank first ..) does but works. Will have something to read tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic function to assign a ranking number to values of `Field2`.

```
select Field1,  Field2,  Field3 from (
    select Field1
            ,  Field2
            ,  Field3 
            , row_number() over (partition by Field1,  Field3 
                                 order by Field2 desc) rn
    from your_table
    )  
where rn = 1
/
```

This implementation assumes a reverse alphabetical sort will produce the correct order for your needs.  If you have a more complicated scheme for prioritization you'll need to apply a transformation of some kind using CASE or DECODE.

Comment: I did the complicated CASE part, But checking your code  dont know if i could make mine simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select col1,MAX(col2) as Col2,Max(Col3) as Col3 from Employee group by Col1
```

If you try to use distinct in one column by selecting multiple column you should use `Max()` or `Min()` to get the values

The problem you will find here is

```
col1  col2    col3
aa     T      qqq 
aa     F      zzz
```

In this case `MAX(col3)` will be `zzz` instead of `qqq`

In this case you have to choose between `Max()` or `Min()` as per your requirements.

Find your solution in fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/257ff/3

Hope that helps

Comment: I like your answer, but not sure if we can asume Field3 is the same value for a single Field1.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza:Sorry I didn't get your point.Will you please edit my SQL fiddle or share a new so that I can check.

Comment: @Saurabh:Glad I came for your help :)

Comment: The problem I saw was with `aa  T   qqq` and `aa  F   zzz` in this case MAX(Field3) will be `zzz` instead of `qqq`. But looks like OP is ok with that.

Comment: In this case you have to choose between  Max() or Min()

Comment: If that is the case you would need modify the query with aditional validation. That is why is important you describe the problem with detail.

Comment: The distinct is unnecessary in your query because of the `group by`

Answer (score 0):

In this query you assign 0 if is 'T'

That way if there is a 'T' will always appear first.

The only assumption I made is 'T' and 'F' appear 1 or less for each Col1. **Please tell me if that is correct**

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aa50/17)

```
with cteEmp as (
    SELECT 
      Col1, Col2, Col3,
      ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY CASE 
                                            WHEN Col2='T' THEN 0 
                                            ELSE 1 
                                         END ) AS row_id    
    FROM Employee
)
SELECT E.* 
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN 
     cteEmp CE ON (E.Col1 = CE.Col1 AND 
                   E.Col2 = CE.Col2 AND
                   CE.row_id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another one getting `Col3` value as per `Col2` and `Col1` irrespective of `Max()` or `Min()` in columns

```
select col1, MAX(col2) as Col2 , 
(select top 1 col3 from Employee as E where E.Col1=Employee.Col1 and 
E.col2 = max(Employee.Col2) order by col3) as Col3 
from Employee 
group
by Col1
```

Find the solution in Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77d2b/2